# TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider and PCI

Tags: encryption

Just a couple of months ago we set up a brand new Server 2016 box, used IIS Crypto to select PCI compliant cyphers...

[image]

Today it failed a PCI compliance scan

```
The remote service supports the use of medium strength SSL ciphers.

TLSv1
  DES-CBC3-SHA                 Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1
```

Disabling TLS 1.0 caused a whole raft of issues, but my main concern is a lot of our web applications use System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider to encrypt/decrypt strings held on our DB.

If we disable Triple DES will these applications then fail to encrypt/decrypt or does it rely on cryptography built in to .NET?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the issue SSLCipher Suite `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` enabled? What changes if you click the `PCI` button?

Comment: It was (and seemingly still is) configured to PCI 3.1

Comment: Looking at this I think you are correct about the cipher to remove - http://serverfault.com/questions/813271/removing-vulnerable-cipher-on-windows-10-breaks-outgoing-rdp - hopefully it will not break something else. It would appear it effects outgoing RDP but not incoming? We need RDP to work and removing TLS 1.0 broke it (that we fixed) and backup notification emails using SSL that we still can

Comment: cannot fix (using Non-SSL connection works)

Comment: Zaph - you were correct, removing that resolved the problem and it passed - if you want to enter that as the answer I can mark it up accordingly :-)